# webpack & babel Error for react when use 'npm start'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I am a new to react. when I use webpack to pack my code,there is a error but I can not find out the cause. here is the error:
this is error:

```
ERROR in ./app/main.jsx
Module parse failed: /home/liudong/Public/proj/Homepage/app/main.jsx             Unexpected token (8:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (8:7)
at Parser.pp$4.raise    (/home/liudong/Public/proj/Homepage/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
```

Here is webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
devtool: 'eval-source-map',
entry: __dirname + '/app/main.jsx',
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js'
},
 resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
},
moudle: {
    loaders:[
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader:"json"
        },
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude:'/node_modules/',
            loader:'babel',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style!css?modules'
        }

    ]
}
```

//dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^15.4.0-rc.4",
"react-dom": "^15.4.0-rc.4",
"react-router": "^2.8.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.17.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
"css-loader": "^0.25.0",
"json-loader": "^0.5.4",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"webpack": "^1.13.2",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
}
```

I hava tried to change loader to "babel-loader", but it did not work.

here is main.jsx:

```
//main.jsx
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import Greeter from './Greeter.jsx'
import './main.css'

render(<Greeter/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Greeter.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import config from './config.json'


class Greeter extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
        <div>
            {config.greetText}
        </div>
     )
  }
}

export default Greeter
```

Comment: Can you add the `main.jsx` file?

Comment: I have added it

Comment: try after removing your css import from main

Comment: the error still exists

Answer (score 0):

Add `json` extension in resolve -

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.json', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
```

Also install `babel`

```
npm install --save-dev babel
```

I don't see it in your `devDependencies`

Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes up because of the word 'module' which be written  as 'moudle'

Comment: Oh. Glag you figured out by yourself. @HioryLiu